# Directed Graph theory

Tags: python, graph

```
Any sequence of vertices v1, v2, ..., vk in a graph G such that (vi, vi+1) is 
an edge for every 1 ≤ i ≤ k-1 is a path.
```

I want to know if this statement is true or false?
Is this statement another way of saying that the graph is a directed graph, therefore, its a one-way "path"???

I know that v_1, ..., v_k is just an arbitrary enumeration of vertices in the graph satisfying the given constraint that (v_i, v_{i+1}) is an edge in your graph.

This is the same format as for defining a (finite) sequence of numbers: "any sequence of numbers n_1, ..., n_k in \N such that n_i+n_{i+1}=n_{i+3}" for example would include sequences [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...] and [0, 0, 0, ...].

Comment: off-topic. Please ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be directed or undirected graph. It's not compulsory that it has to be directed. NetworkX module in Python does it right.

Did you check the documentation of NetworkX module? It will help you in better understanding.